# Build a SelectListItem accessible throughout application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

I'm sure there is a better way to do this but i have not figured it out.  Currently I build this SelectListItem in multiple places throughout my ASP.NET site  (in a couple controllers, a viewmodel, etc).  Lots of cutting and pasting.

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> TimeSlotsList()
        {
            //Build Time Slot Drop Down            
            List<SelectListItem> li1 = new List<SelectListItem>();
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Tues Mar. 15, 09:40am", Value = "1" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Tues Mar. 15, 11:00am", Value = "2" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Tues Mar. 15, 1:10pm", Value = "3" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Tues Mar. 15, 2:10pm", Value = "4" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Tues Mar. 15, 3:30pm", Value = "5" });            
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Wed  Mar. 16, 8:30am", Value = "6" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Wed Mar. 16, 9:30am", Value = "7" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Wed Mar. 16, 11:00am", Value = "8" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Wed Mar. 16, 1:10pm", Value = "9" });
            li1.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Wed Mar. 16, 2:10pm", Value = "10" });            
            return (li1); 
        }
```

How do I build this SelectList once and access it throughout my app with a function like:

```
ViewData["TimeSlots"] = TimeSlotsList();
```

I imagine I can create a folder called "CustomFunctions" and I build a class for it in that folder but how would I delcare it and use it.  Do i need extra using statements?.  Further could I put other Functions that build other lists (like an select list of answers) in that same class or would each function need its own class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a helper class and add a method for each list that you need. The code below is going to create a copy of the list every time the method is called.

**Helper class:**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public static class ListHelper
    {
        public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CreateTimeSlotsList()
        {
            List<SelectListItem> l = new List<SelectListItem>();
            l.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Tues Mar. 15, 09:40am", Value = "1" });
            l.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Tues Mar. 15, 11:00am", Value = "2" });
            l.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Tues Mar. 15, 1:10pm", Value = "3" });
            l.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Tues Mar. 15, 2:10pm", Value = "4" });
            l.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Tues Mar. 15, 3:30pm", Value = "5" });            
            l.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Wed  Mar. 16, 8:30am", Value = "6" });
            l.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Wed Mar. 16, 9:30am", Value = "7" });
            l.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Wed Mar. 16, 11:00am", Value = "8" });
            l.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Wed Mar. 16, 1:10pm", Value = "9" });
            l.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Wed Mar. 16, 2:10pm", Value = "10" });            
            return l;
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public MyController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult MyActionMethod()
        {
            ViewBag["TimeSlots"] = ListHelper.CreateTimeSlotsList();
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesnt like the name static Listhelper, wants a class, delegate, enum, interface or struct.  Am I missing a using statement?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to add the class keyword to the class definition. Sorry about that.